# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(PhotosFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse

Like the title says and I cant figure out what to do and I would appreciate if someone could give me some help.

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

public PhotosFragment(){}
private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ListView lvItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.PhotosFragments);
        // ADD HERE
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        items.add("First Item");
        items.add("Second Item");
        // Setup remove listener method call
        setupListViewListener(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work.

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;

itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

You have to instantiate it first. Like this

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your `itemsAdapter` using

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

and ArrayAdapter expects a `Context` on its constructor ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E))):

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Note that to get a `Context` from your `Fragment` you can use `getActivity()`, but take into account that `getActivity()` can return null if it is called before `onAttach` of the fragment.